# ParallelLogger shows no console output and file output is corrupted

Tags: r, multithreading, logging, parallel-processing

Recently I've started to switch my code to parallel execution using the `foreach` and `doParallel` packages. Logging with `futile.logger` works poorly due to the different threads interfering with each other. So I started to use the `ParallelLogger`, which is supposed to handle logging even in a parallel setting.
Unfortunately I have two issues with this logger that I can't solve on my own, maybe I'm doing something wrong, or there is a bug in the System.

1. The first problem is that despite me creating a Console Appender (See MWE below) no thread is logging onto the console.
2. The logfile produced by my logger is corrupted in a way that `launchLogViewer`throws a `line 40 did not have 6 elements` error.

Here is the MWE:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ParallelLogger)

LOGGING_FILE_PATH <- "Parallel_MWE.log"

diff_time <- function(start_time) {
  format(difftime(Sys.time(), start_time))
}

block_execution <- function(start_se, end_se) {
  logInfo("Start Data Loading")
  start_time_loading <- Sys.time()
  Sys.sleep(2)

  logInfo("Data Loading Done: ", diff_time(start_time_loading))
  logInfo("Start Data Preprocessing")
  start_time_computation <- Sys.time()
  logInfo(paste("Start:", sprintf("%04d", start_se),
   "End:", sprintf("%04d", end_se),
   sep = " "
  ))
  Sys.sleep(2)

  logInfo("Computation Done: ", diff_time(start_time_computation))
  logInfo("Start Data Postprocessing")
  start_time_writing <- Sys.time()
  Sys.sleep(2)

  logInfo("Data Postprocessing Done: ", diff_time(start_time_writing))
  logInfo("Overall time taken: ", diff_time(start_time_whole))
  logInfo("Current allocated Memory: ", memory.size(), " MB\n")
}

registerLogger(createLogger(
  name = "ParLogger",
  threshold = "INFO",
  appenders = list(
    createConsoleAppender(
      layout = layoutSimple
    ),
    createFileAppender(
      layout = layoutParallel,
      fileName = LOGGING_FILE_PATH
    )
  )
))

logInfo("Start Programm")

start_time_whole <- Sys.time()
cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cluster)

start <- 0100
end <- 9000
step <- 0100

foreach(i = seq(start, end, step), .packages = c("ParallelLogger")) %dopar% {
  block_execution(i, (i + step))
}

stopCluster(cluster)
logInfo("Programm Done: ", format(difftime(Sys.time(), start_time_whole)))
clearLoggers()
```

And here is a part of the resulting logfile showing one case of the error:

```
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 4]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Overall time taken: 39.00498 secs
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 4]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Current allocated Memory: 42.01 MB 
cs
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 1]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Overall time taken: 39.07554 secs
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 4]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Start Data Loading
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 2]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Data Postprocessing Done: 2.063492 secs
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 1]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Current allocated Memory: 42.01 MB 
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 1]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Start Data Loading
39.10681 secs
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 3]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Data Postprocessing Done: 2.049974 secs
2018-09-17 10:47:57 [Thread 2]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Current allocated Memory: 42.01 MB


2018-09-17 10:49:15 [Thread 3]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Start: 7500 End: 7600
g
2018-09-17 10:49:15 [Thread 4]  INFO  doParallel  fun  Start: 7600 End: 7700
```

As you can see some lines are warped wrong or cut into parts. If I remove these faulty lines `launchLogViewer` works just fine.

So how can I log a parallel R-script with multiple threads into a file and onto the console? Or how do I get the `ParallelLogger` to log onto a file and console while not corrupting the output?

---

Edit:

Running the MWE under a Linux-system leads to a nicely formatted logfile.
So it seems to be a windows specific problem.

Comment: If you're on Linux or macOS you can use [`rsyslog`](https://github.com/atheriel/rsyslog) to log to syslog and then just monitor syslog for your particular log-lines. It's good way to avoid the issues with file logging in threaded contexts.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm bound to windows, but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The "no log is shown in console" part happens due to to fact that the individual threads don't have a stdout channel so this is not a bug. I talked to the dev about the logfile formatting and it turns out that the `ParallelLogger` dose not have a transaction management, so there is nothing you can do about this topic.